# How to incorporate np.argmax into broadcasting to replace the given for-loop code (if possible)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, array-broadcasting

I have been playing around with Numpy to speed-up code where I can. It really is beautifully fast. However, it does require some clever thinking at times. I suppose practice will make perfect.

Instead of me explaining my problem , here is what I am trying to replace:

```py
# We use U and A to compute V

U = np.array([[1,2],
             [4,3],
             [5,6],
             [7,8]])

V = np.zeros(U.shape)

A = np.array([[1,3],
              [3,4]])

# The for loop to be replaced

for t in range(len(U)):
    V[t] = np.argmax( U[t]*A.T ,axis = 1)
```

My attempt:

```py
V = np.argmax(U[:,np.newaxis]*A.T,axis=1)

# U[:,np.newaxis]*A.T
```

Fear not, I do know what is wrong in my Numpy version. The commented out code does give the correct intermediate, however, I am failing to incorporate the np.argmax part correctly as in my for loop code. I don't think one can perhaps. Please help me if this is possible. I will really appreciate this.

Comment: In your attempt, use `,axis=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the right track, just the wrong axis. Also you don't need to transpose `A`:

```
(A * U[:,np.newaxis]).argmax(-1) # or equivalently axis 2

array([[1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. This is very elegant. I am now going to read up on these new axis configurations (axis = 2 and axis = -1).

Comment: You're welcome @DylanSolms :) don't forget you can upvote answers too

Comment: You can think of applying along a specific axis in terms of the resulting shape you wish to obtain. Say `a` has shape `(4,3,2)`. In this same example you'd want the result to have shape `(4,3)`, hence you want to apply argmax over the last axis, which will be reducing over (getting rid of) the last dimension @DylanSolms